# How to fix problem when parsing less and more data

Tags: php

During parsing, I get the price of the product and enter it into the database. I try to limit the price inside and out so that it doesn't fit into the base, but it doesn't work.

I.e, if the price is less than 8 AND more than 30,000, I need to skip this data and parse the next data.

My code:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {

    if ($value->price < 8 && $value->price > 30000) {
        break;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and continue add to database price less 8 and more than 30000. What i do wrong?

Comment: How can the value be _both_ less than 8, _and_ more than 30000? Did you mean `or` instead, so that any price below 8 gets tossed out, and any price above 30000? `if ($value->price < 8 || $value->price > 30000) {`

Comment: yup, my bad, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use OR (||), instead of AND (&&), as the price cannot be less than 8 and more than 30000 at the same time. Also, it's better to use "continue" instead of break, if you need to keep the loop iterating and do something if your condition didn't meet.

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    if ($value->price < 8 || $value->price > 30000) {
        continue;
    }

    // do something
}
```